# Docker How to save and restore WORKDIR in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, save, dockerfile, restore, working-directory

I have a Dockerfile FROM an image.
I want to modify it and add some files operations that will be relative to different WORKDIR than the one that is given by the FROM image. I want therefore save the WORKDIR to a variable before I modify WORKDIR, and restore WORKDIR from that variable after my commands end. How to do that?

Wanted result:

Dockerfile pseudo code:

```
FROM centos:7
some original commands
some original commands
...
var=WORKDIR #save WORKDIR <== how to do that?

WORDIR /my/path/
my commands
my commands

...
WORKDIR = var # restore path that was before <== how to do that?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a temporary variable in Dockerfile and reuse it later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718033/can-i-create-a-temporary-variable-in-dockerfile-and-reuse-it-later)

Comment: Also note that each `RUN` command runs in its own shell/container, so you can `RUN cd ... && ...` to run a single (command-type) step in an alternate directory without affecting the global `WORKDIR`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an environment variable.

```
ENV WORKDIR=/my/path/
WORDIR $WORKDIR
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to WSMathias9's answer:

Unless the `WORKDIR` was changed by the base image you're using, the default is always `/` in your case you can just set it to `/` when you're finish as it's the default of the `centos` image

But, if you're using `WORKDIR` as a replacement for `cd` just use `cd` in `RUN`

Instead of for example:

```
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /folder
RUN mycommand
```

Do:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN cd /folder && mycommand
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to preserve WORKDIR from the base image then it is not possible

WORKDIR will only have value if you set it within the same dockerfile.

if you are trying to different Working dir for different commands:

Dockerfile pseudo code:

```
FROM centos:7
some original commands
some original commands
...
ARG PATH1=/path1
ARG PATH2=/path1

my commands
my commands

WORKDIR PATH1
my commands
my commands

WORKDIR PATH2
my commands
my commands

WORKDIR PATH1
my commands
my commands

...
WORKDIR PATH1 # restore path that was before <== how to do that?
```